# react-navigation - Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined

Tags: react-navigation

I'm new in React Native and trying create my first app. So I have a question:

I got 2 screens (using react-navigation). At first screen there is a render of app logo with spinner(from native-base) and fetch to the server at the same time. And I need to navigate to another screen only when fetch is over and responce is handled. Please help me find my mistakes!

index.ios.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TextInput,TouchableHighlight
} from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import LoadingScreen from './src/screens/LoadingScreen.js';
import MainContainer from './src/screens/MainContainer.js';

export default class Calculator2 extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <LoadingScreen/>
    );
  }
}
const AppNavigator = StackNavigator({
  Loading: {
    screen: LoadingScreen
   },
  Main: {
    screen: MainContainer
  }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Calculator2', () => Calculator2);
```

LoadingScreen.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AsyncStorage,
  AppRegistry,NetInfo,
  Text,Image,View
} from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import AppNavigator from '../../index.ios.js';
import { Container, Header, Content, Spinner } from 'native-base';

export default class LoadingScreen extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Loading',
  };
  constructor(props){
   super(props);

  }
  componentDidMount(){
    const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;
    fetch('url').then( (response) => {navigate('Main')});
  }
  render() {
    return(
          <View>
            App logo with spinner
          </View>
   );
  }
}
```

MainContainer.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,Alert,NetInfo,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,ActivityIndicator,
  TextInput,TouchableHighlight
} from 'react-native';

import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import AppNavigator from '../../index.ios.js';

export default class MainContainer extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Main',
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View  style={{flexDirection: 'column'}}>
         ...
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

And all I got is an error "Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined" at LoadingScreen.componentDidMount

UPD
actually my fetch should be a function getting responce and handling it, and it should wait till handling is done:

```
async function getData(){
    var response = await fetch('url', {
      method: 'GET'
    });
    storage = await response.json(); // storage for response
    regions = Object.keys(storage); // an array of regions names
    console.log(storage, Object.keys(storage));
  };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to register AppNavigator component instead of Calculator2

```
AppRegistry.registerComponent('Calculator2', () => AppNavigator);
```

Comment: maybe you can help me with my fetch too - it should handle responce and get list of regions, which is need for render picker. but picker at next screen is render faster then list is appear and has 'undefine' value

Comment: You can pass the regions as params in the navigate function like `navigate('Main', { regions })` and in the Main screen you can access from the state https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/navigation-prop#state-The-screen's-current-stateroute prop of navigation. like `this.props.navigation.state.params.regions`.

Comment: when i'm trying console.log this.props.navigation.state.params.regions at the Main screen where my Picker is rendered I got [ ] in Debugger's console first and only after - Navigation Dispatch: 
createNavigationContainer.js:127 Action:  Object {type: "Navigation/NAVIGATE", routeName: "Main", params: Object, action: undefined}
params: Object
regions: Array(0)
length: 0      so my navigate('Main', { regions }) pass empty array, not handled responce (which also logged at the console a bit later)

Answer (score 0):

Just update your LoadingScreen.js's componentDidMount function as following:

```
componentDidMount() {
 var self = this;
   fetch('url').then( (response) => {
        self.props.navigation.navigate('Main')
   });
}
```

Comment: then I got in RN Debugger "Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined"

Comment: Make sure you are getting a promise returned from the called API. Cehck that using console.log inside the fetch's callback and comment out the navigation line.

Comment: I've added UPD to the start question. fetch is work nice but I'm not sure how I should it work together